# Delete from a table where the id of user is equal to the id on another table where user email

Tags: mysql

I'm looking how to delete something from a table where the result from another query on another table.

I need to delete from "contract" where id is equal to the id of the user, where the email is equal to email@gmail.com.

Something like " DELETE FROM contract WHERE user = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = 'testuser****@mailinator.com') "

So I can delete all the contracts from user 3 but without using it's id because I just know the email. (I seed the testusers with a script so I have the email but no the id)

contract
[image]

users
[image]

Comment: I think that a good to create a storeProcedure.

Comment: please read up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You must have a column witch exists in table 1 and in table 2( foreign) you Do something like delete from table1 where id in( select id from table2 where ....)

Comment: Thanks all. Noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete using `INNER JOIN`:

```
DELETE c FROM contract c 
INNER JOIN users u
ON c.user = u.id
WHERE u.email = 'testuser****@mailinator.com'
```